# Adding DbContextOptions in Startup.cs not registering data store

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

My problem is that the below code does not register a data store during startup. This is the specific "error" statement I get in the response from the application:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: No data stores are configured. Configure a data store by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.
    Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.DataStoreSelector.SelectDataStore(ServiceProviderSource providerSource)
```

In ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) I am trying to specify DbContextOptions for my DbContext in a lambda. Code:

```
services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration)
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
        options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"))
    );
```

In my DbContext, I have a constructor which sends the option to base, code:

```
public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
```

My configuration file config.json, which is read at startup, contains this connectionstring:

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
        "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=MyDbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
    }
}
```

I have previously used

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Startup.Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));

}
```

in my DbContext successfully. It registers the data store and it works properly, but I'd rather use the lambda way.

If there is any more information needed, I'll provide it.

Comment: Yeah, seems the Lambda way isn't working properly in beta 4, I'm having the same issue when trying to perform migrations

Comment: @RonDeFreitas Yeah, I am on beta3 at the moment, but I guess I just have to wait until they fix it, just thought it was strange that EF 7 on github has the lambda way as an example on how to set DbContextOptions. Thanks by the way, good to know I am not alone in this matter.

Answer (score 6):

Are you injecting your context into your controller or wherever you are using it? I discovered that if you try to new up the context instead of injecting it, it does not use the configuration specified in Startup.cs

Comment: I am injecting my DbContext. So, it's not that sadly.

Comment: Wierd... this is my context on beta4 and it's working fine
services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'll give it a try tomorrow. Also I am going to upgrade to beta4, if it won't be a hassle. Started out with beta2, and the upgrade was painful between 2 and 3. Migrations and class renaming in Microsoft.MVC, not fun. I'll let you know how it went tomorrow.

Comment: Migrations from 3->4 was pretty nasty as well

Comment: I've tried your example code in beta3, did not work with my project, still got the same error. In config.json, the name is the same as yours. I decided to go for a static class that reads the config file at startup, and when my DbContexts needs that information, they'll ask the static class for it. I have a project structure where I seperate the dbcontext in its own project together with my repositories. Thank you though! I won't migrate to beta4 then, project due tomorrow so, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

I (still) have the same problem with EF7 and beta 4. This is my workaround in my data context:

```
public class AspNetDataContext : IdentityDbContext, IDataContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public AspNetDataContext(DbContextOptions options)
    {
        _connectionString = ((SqlServerOptionsExtension)options.Extensions.First()).ConnectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

I extract the connectionstring from the options and use this in the OnConfiguring method. This is still not the solution we want, but I don't have to change something in the Startup.cs (everything there is like you described). And as soon this is fixed, you just have to remove the stuff from the data context class.
And maybe someone has another (and even better) solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private string _connectionString { get; set; }
    public MyContext(string connectionString) //Inject external connectionstring.
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    public MyContext(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) : base(options.Options) //Default binding from web.config.
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured && false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString)) // if no default binding
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString); //Use provider as SQL server and make connection through connection string.
            optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(_factory);//optional, Use Logger factory
        }
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder); //configure connection

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you comment on that code even if it's self-explanatory?:)

Answer (score -1):

EF7 has new sytax from DBContextOptionsBuilder to EntityOptionsBuilder. Following is ready to use for also command line scaffolding.

```
public class ContentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContentCategory> ContentCategories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(EntityOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString");
    }
}
```