# C# Problem with DbContext: Argument 1: cannot convert 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'

Tags: c#, database, string, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I've got some problem with `DbContext`. I decided to make a new class, which will be responsible for connections with DataBase.

```
public class PetAlertContext : DbContext
{
    public PetAlertContext() : base("PetAlert") { }

    public DbSet<Zwierze> Zwierzaki { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Osoba> Osoby { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Placowka> Placowki { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ogloszenie> Ogloszenia { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I have some exception near the name of base:

> Argument 1: cannot convert 'string' to
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'.

I found a similar issue and response with some code like this, but I have a little problem with understanding this construction.

Would You be so kind to help me with that? I commented these out:

```
public PetAlertContext(string connectionString) : base(GetOptions(connectionString))
{
}

private static DbContextOptions GetOptions(string connectionString)
{
    return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString).Options;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The constructor for Entity Framework Core does not take a single string as a parameter, it takes a `DbContextOptions` instance. See [the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.-ctor?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext__ctor_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptions_). The constructor you are currently trying to use is the EF6 constructor which does take just the connection string as the parameter ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.-ctor?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)). The code you have commented out in your question shows you how to instantiate an instance of `DbContextOptions` i.e. by using a `DbContextOptionBuilder` as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions?view=efcore-2.1). So assuming you are using a SQL Server database you can use that code.

Comment: Thank You for help and for useful tips! :) I will get to know with documentation to find some solution!

Comment: Thanks for this info. Answer with EF Core connection is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67783702/1548275